# How to get the Instagram Media ID of particular Post in iOS?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, instagram-api

When user try to share the video on Instagram it will open the Insta Library and the it will get share, I done that but I need the media ID of that shared video. Or it will be do it any another way like PHP or nay?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried to do to solve your problem? Do you have some code that is not behaving the way you expect? Your question is unfortunately not specific about what you're having trouble with, nor what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to call  This API From my APP "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/MEDIA_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN", But for this I need the MEDIA_ID.. which is something like @"1234567894561231236_33215652". I use the Insta Document https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/ but it is manual process & I want this programatically.....